# How can I get all my links to scroll to the top of the page by placing one function in a coldfusion code

Tags: javascript

This is the function that I currently have.
Instead of one link I want all my links to scroll to the top of the page. The function is to be placed within a coldfusion code.

```
<script>
function ScrollClick() {
         // Scroll to top

                 document.body.scrollTop = document.documentElement.scrollTop = 0;

        // Open up a link in my iframe
 document.getElementById('MainWindow').src="DocDisplayCategory.cfm?categoryID=89"
            }
</script>   
</li>
```

Comment: Can you post an example of a link that would show up in the page which you'd want to scroll to the top?

Comment: My links are really categories that are being pulled from the database. As you can see "DocDisplayCategory.cfm?categoryID=89" is what would be displayed in my iframe. I need more than one of the categoryIDs to scroll to the top. I need all of them to scroll to the top.

Comment: In the browser, there's no concept of a "category", just anchor tags, etc.  Are you trying to get an anchor tag inside the iframe to scroll the document outside the iframe?

Comment: Here is an example of the link: http://iecss.com/DocDisplayCategory.cfm?CategoryID=47

Comment: I'm trying to get the whole page to scroll to the top when any of the links are clicked.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how you'd do it with jQuery, in case that's an option for you:

```
$("body").on("click", "a", function(){
  $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, "slow");
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/sL2vA/2/

UPDATE: To help clear up confusion regarding ColdFusion, you'd simply add this to the head of your template (assuming jQuery isn't already available):

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

And put the above code wherever appropriate in your application (in the template footer, in an external JS file, whatever). Wrap it in a script tag if it's in the template.

Comment: Also, I'm adding this function into coldfusion.

Comment: I'm not sure what "I'm adding this function into coldfusion" means, this is Javascript, not CFML. You can have CFML write JS, but they don't interact much more than that.

Comment: Im trying to add a function into my coldfusion code that will allow the the links that are clicked in my menu to automatically scroll to the top of the page.

Comment: @user1970812, you should actually try the suggested answer.  ColdFusion sends html to the browser so the ColdFusion part is not really relevent.

Comment: Solution updated. Hopefully it's more clear now. Use the jQuery I provided as you would any other JavaScript, and add the jQuery script tag in the head of the page.